SQL Oracle - requiero devolver registros que no contengan valores específicos de una columna

Tengo la siguiente tabla de movimientos donde se muestran datos de una factura, donde invoice_ck es el ID de la factura, lo que requiero es que me muestre el ID único de la factura si es que la factura no tenga los tipos 25 o 26 de la columna operation_type, en este caso la consulta no debería mostrarme valor alguno, probé haciendo subconsulta con NOT IN (25 , 26) inner join desde mi tabla principal y not existis, ayuda por favor.
Intento 1:
    select distinct a.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK from CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS a
inner join CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS b on b.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK = a.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK
where not exists (select null 
                FROM CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS c
                where c.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK = a.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK
                and a.OP_OPERATION_TYPE not in (26, 25));

Intento 2:
select inv.IN_ID_INVOICE_cK
from CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS c,
CAVFNDB.INVOICES INV 
where inv.IN_ID_INVOICE_cK = c.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK
and c.OP_OPERATION_TYPE not in (26, 25)
group by inv.IN_ID_INVOICE_cK
having count (distinct c.OP_OPERATION_TYPE) > 1;


Hola John, para que podamos ayudarte, por favor presiona [edit] y agrega la consulta SQL que has intentado, un ejemplo de los datos iniciales, el resultado obtenido y el deseado.

@Marcos acabo de agregar las queries que he estado intentando.

A ver si entendi, vos queres obtener únicamente los IN_ID_INVOICE_cK de aquellos invoices que no tengan OP_OPERATION_TYPE in (26, 25), correcto?

Correcto @Marcos esa es la casuística.

No entiendo como el query simple no te funciona... no entiendo porque haces joins, o group by... o sea.. un query simple con un not in ya funcionaria.. pero algo no estas mostrando que hace que te muestre registros de mas...

@gbianchi es porque la tabla que muestro tiene un ID_OPERATION que hace que los registros se dupliquen.

y como podemos ayudarte si no vemos eso??? o sea.. vos me preguntas como evitar que se muestren.. y es con not in... nada mas.. si tenes otras condiciones, necesitamos verlas.. no hacemos magia :(

@gbianchi la primera imagen está clara.

Tu primer intento tiene un pequeño problema con la condición del tipo de operación. Lo que necesitas es que consultar las facturas que sí tengan esos tipos para usar NOT EXISTS sobre esa consulta. Al final quedaría así:
SELECT DISTINCT a.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
FROM        CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                FROM CAVFNDB.OPERATIONS c
                WHERE c.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK = a.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK
                AND   c.OP_OPERATION_TYPE IN (26, 25) --Esta condición tiene que ser con la tabla de la subconsulta y positiva
                ); 

Por cierto, tampoco necesitabas el JOIN.

Genial la explicación, acabo de probar tu solución y funciona bien.

Voy a aceptar tu respuesta como la solución ya que se tarda mucho menos que la solución de Marcos, muchas gracias!

Para obtener los IN_ID_INVOICE_FK de aquellos invoices que no tengan OP_OPERATION_TYPE in (26, 25), podes hacerlo así:

Creas una consulta que obtenga los IN_ID_INVOICE_FK de los invoices que si tengan OP_OPERATION_TYPE IN (25,26).
Ejemplo:
SELECT DISTINCT IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
FROM OPERATIONS
WHERE OP_OPERATION_TYPE IN (25,26)



A esta consulta la podes usar como:
Opción 1: Una sub-consulta en un NOT IN
SELECT DISTINCT IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
FROM OPERATIONS
WHERE IN_ID_INVOICE_FK NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
    FROM OPERATIONS
    WHERE OP_OPERATION_TYPE IN (25,26)
);

Demo

Opción 2: Un CTE
WITH TEMP_INVOICES AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
  FROM OPERATIONS
  WHERE OP_OPERATION_TYPE IN (25,26)
)
SELECT DISTINCT O.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK 
FROM OPERATIONS O
    LEFT JOIN TEMP_INVOICES T
        ON O.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK = T.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK
WHERE T.IN_ID_INVOICE_FK IS NULL;

Demo

Muchas gracias, te comento que la opción 1 se tarda mucho y como tengo muchos registros, se queda colgado; mientras que la segunda opción también se toma su tiempo pero se ejecuta con lentitud.
